# Follow Active Quads on multiple UV islands at the same time?

Tags: uv

Is their a way to square all these up at the same time?
I can only get 'follow active quads' to work on one island at a time.

[image]

Comment: If you reset and re-unwrap what does it give? Have you tried the UV Squares addon?

Comment: Same results from reset and unwrap, Ive heard about UV sqaures, Ill look into it!